# mysql.connect, for looping databases

Tags: python, mysql, database

after connecting the database server I want to loop certain databases.
The names of the databases are in the list dbList. These names were taken from different customer files with lines like
`name_database='database_1'` or 
`name_database='database-2'`.
The shortened dbList looks like ["'database_1'", "'database-2'"].
If I for-loop the database list (removing the single quotes from the database name, do some action) all is fine except in the name of the database is a hyphen. Than the program stops with the error

1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-2' at line 1 
That is exactly where I call

```
dbConn.database=dbName
```

I tried various "dbConn.database=..." ways; nothing worked.
The only way it works is to not use the loop-variable; just write dbConn.database='database-2' 
But this is not my intention.

coding extract is:

```
import mysql.connector
```

...
    dbConn = connect2dbServer ( loginParameterFile, fileSection )

authentication for DB server access in general (no DB selected)
connect2dbServer fetches  user name, password, server IP, and port number
connect2dbServer returns the DB server connector.

...

```
for dbName in dbList:
     dbName = removeChar ("'", dbName)
     dbConn.database=dbName           # connecting with (next) DB
     # ...


    select round (sum(size)/1024/1024/1024, 2) as 'Used HDD space (GB)' from oc_filecache where path in ('cache', 'documents', 'files')
```

## ...  # and some more queries

---

```
import re
def removeChar (char, string):
    stripped=''
    stripped = re.sub(char, "", string) 
    return stripped
```

---

OS macOS 10.12
mysql client 5.7
mysql-connector 2.1.5
python 3.6

If you need more information please ask for.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to first of all go read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Someone read it. Someone could find the answer to the question. Thank you CBroe for pointing at this page.